# Can't login to MySQL after upgrade to Lion

Tags: mysql, osx-lion

After upgrading to Lion I can still start MySQL via System Preferences -> MySQL

When I try and login with the root user and password I was using on Snow Leopard I get this error via phpMyAdmin

`#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server`

Via the MySQL Query Browser however I get code 2003

If I try via Terminal with mysql -u root -p I get the error

`-bash: mysql: command not found`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p` in bash.

Comment: That gives me

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Then there's a password set for root that's not the one you're giving it. I know there are password recovery (or rather change) procedures, nothing I can help you with though, sorry.

Comment: I tried leaving the password blank and that logged me in.

I've updated the root password via the command line.

I can now log in using the query browser but phpMyAdmin and my websites are still giving an error 2002

Comment: Can you log in using the mysql command prompt as the user your web sites are logging in as?

Comment: Yeah I'm using the same username and password throughout as it's only local dev sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the socket and I had to change occurences of /var/mysql/mysql.sock to /tmp/mysql.sock as stated here http://birdchan.com/home/2011/07/20/osx-lion-mysql-sock-path/